# How can I map elements of one enum to another?

Tags: c, enums, dictionary

I'm using C. I have to large enums, one of menu ID's and one of window ID's. At the moment they're mapped to each other by an array, so the elements have to be put into the array perfectly and as soon as something changes work has to be done to put them all back into the right place. What would be a better way of mapping the menus to the windows? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you explicitly assigning values to the members of each `enum`?  How do menu IDs map to window IDs?  Can you post part of the enums as an example?

If the `enums` are lengthy, this might be a good candidate for a code-generating script.  Store your IDs in (for example) a CSV file that lists matching pairs of Window IDs and Menu IDs.  Then, write a script that parses the CSV file and generates a header containing the appropriate `enum` definitions.  If you are building your project using makefiles (or similar), it should be fairly straightforward to integrate this type of auto-generated header into your build system.

Comment: Both the menu IDs and the windowIDs are already generated from XML, but they are quite separate because the windows are used for more than just menus. I'm not explicitly assigning values to the enums, there's just a function which returns the window from an array of windows at the element of the input menuID at the moment.

Comment: Are menu IDs mapped one-to-one with window IDs?  Better yet, can you post some example code as to what your current code is doing (part of the `enum`s plus an example of the function that you mentioned)?